# Web scraping CNN data

Tags: python, finance, scrape, stocks

I have a question- does CNN permit you to scrape data if it's for your own personal use? for instance, if i wanted to write a quick program that would scrape the price of a certain stock, can i scrape CNN money?

I've just started learning python so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory I am not a lawyer.

In CNN's [terms of use page](https://www.cnn.com/terms) it states that

> You may not modify, publish, transmit, participate in the transfer or
> sale, create derivative works, or in any way exploit, any of the
> content, in whole or in part.
>
> You may download copyrighted material
> for your personal use only

So it looks like if you do it for personal use only and don't share any of the results of the work you would be fine.

However, some sites can scrapers automatically if they issue too many requests, so be sure to rate-limit your scraping, and don't request too many pages.